# Shift neighboring grid cells (without complete reorder)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

Using bootstrap v4.0, I am working on a site layout that shows right-side "sidebar" when screen is in XL mode. there are many many items in the sidebar. i want to switch places 2 boxes somewhere in the middle of it.

in Bootstrap 3 you could gradually shift cells left or right. Bootstrap 4, i can see there's a way to reorder whole column, and there's a way to send cell to be first or last. but i cannot figure out how to shift 1 cell only 1 step (basically, jump over the neighbor cell). in my situation, see how 2 and 3 (should) change order when resizing from L to XL

```
000000000       000000 1111
1111 2222  ==>  000000 3333
333333333       000000 2222
444444444       000000 4444
555555555       000000 5555
```

i did find solution for my given situation by applying **order-xl-N** classes to all of the sidebar boxes (applying them to just some boxes doesn't seem to work). feels like an overshot.. so i am curious maybe i am missing something? if sidebar has 20 items, do they all need to have order-N classes to have just 2 of them switched places in the middle of the stack?

here's my personal situation html markup.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-xl-8">box 0</div> 
    <div class="col-12 col-xl-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-12">box 1</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-12">box 2</div>
            <div class="col-12 d-block">box 3</div>
            <div class="col-12">box 4</div>
            <div class="col-12">box 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

while i do seek an elegant solution to my situation, a generalized one would also be great.. on some pages i prioritize box 5 and place it on top of XL sidebar, thus to avoid complicated ordering logic, i want my classes to affect only boxes 2 and 3.. all of this for my [facebook video downloader](https://fbvid.org/) project.. social social video downloading..

Comment: Please post the HTML markup

Comment: i think my html markup is irrelevant, - this is a generalized question. but if you insist, its <div class=row><div id=box0></div><div id=box1></div><div id=box2></div><div id=box3></div><div id=box4></div></div>. vertical or horizontal, this doesn't matter, i just want to figure out if neighbor cells can be switched places in bootstrap 4.0, as it was possible with 3.3..

Comment: Post the code in the question itself. The `.row` class is only used to contain `.col-*`. I don't see the `col-*` class.

Comment: i have fully revamped the question but the title of it.. hopefully this will change things?

Answer (score 0):

- yes you have to use CSS3 flexboxes to reorder your divs.
- you can save code by replacing col-12 col-lg-7 by col-lg-7 only. Try it you'll see.